# Protractor/Webdriver loses synchronization after a series of calls made to the browser

Tags: angularjs, protractor, ui-automation, karma-jasmine

I am running a set of tests that validates URLs and a few HTML/Angular items on many views of a site. Basically the tests grabs an icon in a left panel (that moves in and out as you hover), then a menu comes out with buttons that you can click on. Once the menu comes out and the 1st tier of buttons are shown, another set of buttons are able to be clicked (a sub-menu).

When I hover over the sub-menu buttons and i click these buttons, I am sent to a page/view where I am able to do my assertions/validations.

The menu will disappear at this time until I hover back over the icon and do the aforementioned actions once again. All of my tests pass except one that has up to 15 sub-buttons to click. I tried to reverse the order thinking it was because a few buttons were not visible at the time, but again the test fail.

Has anyone come across a situation where their tests fail after running a lot of actions back to back at the browser? 
i'm thinking I am over loading the driver or something...

I am getting the below error:

```
 Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

    3 specs, 1 failure
    Finished in 63.217 seconds

ui-platform/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:113
  var template = new Error(this.message);
```

Answer (score 5):

As Shaunhusain has explained you have to increase your default time out interval. Update your conf.js file with below tag, here's the [link](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#timeouts-from-jasmine) for more info -

```
  jasmineNodeOpts: { 
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000 //increase the time to avoid async errors (milliseconds)
  }
```

On the other hand you can also update your **onPrepare()** function to include implicit/pageLoadTimeout waits. This can help too.

```
  onPrepare: function(){
     // implicit and page load timeouts
     browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60000);
     browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(35000);
  }
```

There is another method to put in delay. If at all you are getting Async error for any particular spec then you can add delay to that particular spec only. Here's an example -

```
describe("Test", function(){
  it("First Spec", function(){
    //your code here
  },60000);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the simple answer also. It helped with getting the right value first before I use parameterization to custom my wait time.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to extend the DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL perhaps the browser is using a lot of CPU (or waiting on transitions or something of that nature) and not able to complete the operations in the window provided by default:

http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support

`jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000;`

Comment: Both of your answers worked when i tried them. I do like the ability to parameterize the tests, however using the default setting in config gives me the ability to try out a value first, then use parameterization to find the right fit.

Answer (score -1):

try to use

```
directConnect=true
```

see 
https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/server-setup.md#connecting-directly-to-browser-drivers

Sometimes using locally a SeleniumGrid is not working very well or is stable ...